# FFmpeg How can I use the last frame of zoompan for a crossfade

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

The code I have works (sort-of). To try it, input two images of 640*480px.

Or, see a sample here: http://128.199.50.223/videos/test_12_temp.mp4

You can watch from 15 seconds to see the issue.

When you try it, you will see that it zooms in, then fades*, then shows the second image.

*Here is where the issue occurs.
You will notice that just as the fade starts the [crossfade] takes over. Since the [crossfade] uses the origional photo and not the last frame of the zoompan there is a jump back to the image before it was zoomed (as least this is how I understand it).

So, my question is, how can I use the last frame of the zoompan (or continue the zoompan) for the fade.

Here's the code:

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -i images/25_test/31630738_0.jpg \
-loop 1 -t 10 -i images/25_test/31630738_4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=iw*10:ih*10,zoompan=z='min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.0015,1.5)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480[firstclip]; \
 [1:v]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,setsar=1/1[secondclip]; \
 [0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc]; \
 [1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc]; \
 [fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein]; \
 [fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout]; \
 [fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo]; \
 [fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo]; \
 [fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade]; \
 [firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3[output]" \
-map [output] videos/output.mp4
```

There are also some issues with data alignment and timing caused by the zoompan, but those issues may be for another question topic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg \
-i images/25_test/31630738_0.jpg \
-loop 1 -i images/25_test/31630738_4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=yuva420p,scale=iw*10:ih*10,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480[first]; \
 [1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,trim=0:10,setpts=PTS+9/TB[second]; \
 [first][second]overlay" out.mp4
```

The zoompan continues into the crossfade. The `yuva420p` for the first image is not really indeed; only added to improve speed (a bit).

The above command works for me as is, but as per comments, one can add `fifo` to the filterchains to avoid frame drops with slow processors or very large images.

```
[0:v]format=yuva420p,scale=iw*10:ih*10,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=250:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':s=640x480,fifo[first]; \
[1:v]format=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,trim=0:10,setpts=PTS+9/TB,fifo[second];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This creates the following error: `[Parsed_overlay_7 @ 0xdb1480] [framesync @ 0xdb1568] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.`
It seems to drop all the overlay frames. Here is a link to re the resulting render: http://128.199.50.223/videos/super_user_test_1_temp.mp4

Comment: Add `fifo` to second filterchain i.e. `setpts=PTS+9/TB,fifo[second]`.

Comment: It works if I add it to both filter chains! Thanks!